# MATLAB: loop-less conversion of vector to logical matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I want to convert a vector of integers into a logical matrix. This is how I want to do it. Let's say the vector is of size M, and the maximum element is A. The output should be a logical matrix of size MxA, where each row with value v_i is 0 from column 1 to (v_i - 1), and is 1 from column v_i to A. Here's an example:

```
3
4
4
1
```

The output should be:

```
0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

I can do this quite easily with a loop but is there a loop-less way to do it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. First define your data:

```
vector = [3; 4; 4; 1];
M = length(vector);
A = 4;
```

Then (using `bsxfun`):

```
output = bsxfun(@ge, 1:A, vector(:));
```

Alternatively (with `repmat`):

```
output = repmat(1:A,M,1) >= repmat(vector(:),1,A);
```

Comment: Oh nice, I really wasn't thinking of it in simple terms :)